# How can I get MatLab to loop through rows in an Excel sheet and plot the data in subplots?

Tags: excel, matlab, for-loop, graph, subplot

I have data in an excel spreadsheet that I want to import to MatLab to plot in 3D. I want a different plot to display for each row of data. The rows are B3:P3 through B74:P74.
I am thinking a *for loop* would work best, but I can't get the syntax right to have it read from where the data starts to when it ends.

What I have is messy because I have been trying different things.
This is what I have so far:

```
datasetstart = xlsread('data.xlsx', 'sheet', 'B3:P3');
datasetend = xlsread('data.xlsx', 'sheet', 'B74:P74');


%what are your x values 
%x = dataset(rows, columns) x&y are the locations of TCs
x = xlsread('data.xlsx', 'sheet', 'U3:U17');
y = xlsread('data.xlsx', 'sheet', 'V3:V17');
%specify grid points on mesh grid
v_x = linspace(-10,10,50);
v_y = linspace(-5,5,50);
%build 2D mesh
[xx,yy] = meshgrid(v_x,v_y); mesh(xx,yy,ones(50,50))

for time_loop = datasetstart:datasetend
%     subplot(x,y,time_loop); mesh(z,y,time_loop); title('works');
%     plot3(x,y,time_loop,'.');
%     f2 = figure(1);
%     zz = griddata(x,y,time_loop,xx,yy);
%     time = y;
end

z = xlsread('data.xlsx', 'sheet', 'B3:P3');

plot3(x,y,z,'.');

% imported data
zz = griddata(x,y,z,xx,yy);

f2 = figure(1); clf; hold on;
set(f2, 'renderer', 'zbuffer');

surf(xx,yy,zz);
shading flat;
%contour3(xx,yy,zz,30)
title('Thermal Plot at time')
%x axis
xlabel('x location (inches)')
%y axis
ylabel('y location (inches)')
%z axis
zlabel('z temperature (Celsius)')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, your problem is not about plotting, but about iterating over some rows from an excel document. You can do this by generating your range on the fly as follows:

```
... %read x and y data

for i = 3:74
    range = ['B', num2str(i), ':P', num2str(i)];
    z = xlsread('data.xlsx', 'sheet', range);

    ... % create the plots you want for the current z values
end
```